# How to send asynchronous data in an RxJS Observable to a dropdown in angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rest, rxjs

I am trying to bring data( strings) sent from a rest API to a dropdown menu on an online form. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong in my code, as it used to work, but now I am getting null / empty arrays coming in.

I've tried switching around a lot of the array names, and trying to match things up, but I can't seem to make sense of things. I feel like I need to have my original array of strings that is filled with the subscribe method mentioned again, but I am not certain.

Variable/Method explanations:

`nameService`: instance of name-service.ts. this brings in the Observable array of strings from the api.

`names`: a string array initialized empty, to be filled with the retrieved names

`nameSearch`: the formControl Name for the element that contains the filtered search in the html and can be referenced in the .ts.

`filteredNames`: an observable string array to be sent to the html object full of the names. not sure if I can bypass going through so many arrays, but my code is based off the angular Mat-Autocomplete filtered search template found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

`names()`: getter method in the nameService. does not take params.

```
//In the NgOnInit:

this.nameService.names().subscribe(res => this.names= res).add( () => {
      console.log(this.names); //last place data is not null

      this.filteredNames = this.NameSearch.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      )
      }
    )
//Outside NgOnInit custom _filter method, if this helps:

private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log(value);
    const filterVal = value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(filterVal);
    let result = this.opts.filter(opt =>
      opt.toLowerCase().includes(filterVal)
    )
  }
//in the HTML:
    <mat-card class="item">
                    <label> Name:
            <br>
            <mat-form-field hintLabel="Pick your name or enter a new one">
              <input type="text" matInput formControlName="nameSearch" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let name of filteredNames | async" [value]="name">
                  {{ name }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
          </label>
                </mat-card>
```

I want the dropdown to have the list of names pulled in from the database displayed, but right now nothing is coming through. In my error tracing thusfar, I have found that the loss of data happens in the NgOnInit method, where I have commented in the code. I have tried putting the this.names object in the pipe function to no avail.

Comment: Consider changing the title of this post. The problem is not just asynchronous data, but an RxJs Observable. The Angular version is relevant here, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I updated this according to your response. Does this work? Also I noticed that you have `<label>` including the whole input field, is that correct?

```
//In the NgOnInit:

this.names$ = this.nameService.names();
this.nameSearch$ = this.NameSearch.valueChanges(pipe(startWith('')));

this.filteredNames$ = combinelatest(this.names$, nameSearch$).pipe(
  (names, search)=> names.filter(name=>name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
  );


//in the HTML:
<mat-card class="item">
  <label> Name:</label>
  <br>
  <mat-form-field hintLabel="Pick your name or enter a new one">
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="nameSearch" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>

    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let name of filteredNames$ | async" [value]="name">
        {{ name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: that's what I'm going for. my goal was to bring in all the names to start, then filter the list as the user types, as I want to be able to place my cursor in it and have all of the names pop up to scroll through. I would think that in my `NgOnInit` method I would need to use `this.names` again but I don't know where. also, res.names is not an object I can use, and you aren't able to pass anything to the `names()` method, it just gets info from the API and brings it into the app; my filtering only happens at this level.  Also, ` _filter` as written only takes a `string` and not `string[]`. thx!

Comment: yes label does hold the whole input field. its that way on a lot of other elements in my form and it has caused issues before but those were syntax errors and whole project wouldn't compile.

Comment: Gotcha. In general I like to keep subscribe logic outside of my component and let Angular take care of it for me. I hope my change is helpful!

Comment: I added some edits to the top, your solution is now closer to working, but in the this.nameSearch$ line, nameSearch isn't an observable array, its a FormControl Element name. thanks for your help thusfar, I appreciate it!

Comment: Try formControl.get('NameSearch').valueChanges(pipe... where 'formControl' is the reference to the formGroup you are using.

Comment: A few minor points: 1. I recommend changing your getter method to something like `this.nameService.getNames()` to help distinguish from `this.names`. 2. `Observable.combineLatest()` uses camelCase. 3. I highly recommend lodash for working with Observables. `_.filter` is super useful.

Comment: What about something like this:
`this.filteredNames = this.names
.combineLatest(this.NameSearch.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).startWith(''))
.map(([names, search]) => search ? names.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) : names);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<mat-option>` doesn't know what `[value]="name"` is. 
Can you wrap the `<mat-option>` in a `<div>` and put the `*ngFor` on that?

Also, if you do an async pipe on the `ngFor` you shouldn't need to do another one internally.

```
<div *ngFor="let name of filteredNames | async">
  <mat-option [value]="name">
    {{ name }}
  </mat-option>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I did a test and I am incorrect about my first point.`<mat-option>` should know what `[value]="name"` is but maybe there's a problem with the double-pipe

Comment: ok good to know. I removed the pipes in the `{{ name}}` bit, and that didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Try using debounceTime instead of pipe. `this.NameSearch.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).startWith('')).map( ... )`

Comment: is that extra ')' after the `startWith('')` intentional? also, what library is debounceTime() from?

Comment: Good catch. That was a typo. `this.NameSearch.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).startWith('').map( ... )` https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html